# Net Core 2.0 looking for appsettings.Production.json

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have created a couple of these .net core 2 web app and no issue until this one.

Running local under IISExpress it runs correctly but when I deploy a debug version to an IIS folder on the server I have issues.

When I read the config entry it is not found:

```
_config["MySettings:MyName"];
```

files contents:

**appsettings.Development.json**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Trace",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  },
  "MySettings": {
    "MyName": "JohnDoe"
  }
}
```

**appsettings.json**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "Debug": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Trace"
      }
    },
    "Console": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**launchSetting.json**

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:60668/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "api/security",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "WebApi.ViewerSecurity": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "api/security",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:60669/"
    }
  }
}
```

If I copy appsettings.Development.json and rename to appsettings.Production.json it works.

I changed the value of "MyName" in the prod file and logged it. Yup, reading from appsettings.Production.json.

How and why? Production isn't defined anywhere.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The default of `ConfigurationBuilder` is looking for `appsettings.<EnvironmentName>.json` file, so based on the environment that you are working with, the name of this file is changed. and when you are in IIS Express you are in `Development` and when you deploy your application your environment is `Production`. This is why you need `appsettings.Production.json`.

When you are debugging there's a Environment Variable called `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` which is set to `Development` and in your deploy where `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` is not set, the default is `Production`

Comment: What is changing the environment to Production. I don't see any environmental variables set anywhere

Comment: If `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` isn't set, it will default to `Production`.

Comment: is this documented?

Comment: @ginalster yes, here's the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: @Kahbazi with .NET 6 (not core) now released, I haven't been able to find .NET 6 specific documentation regarding the use of environmental variables. Do they function the same way?